# Is VPS hosting is more flexible than cloud

Tags: cloud, vps

we are looking to host an JAVA based application and considering VPS hosting.I want to know if it is a cost effective option over the cloud and I have seen that VPS providers offer linux box with JVM installed in addition we can setup our own desired infrastructure. Please suggest your opinions.

Comment: What is the cloud? Isn't VPS hosting a kind of cloud-hosting?

Comment: @Jonas Iam now aware of the difference between cloud and VPS hosting ... but by saying clound I mean services like Amazon webservice etc.

Comment: VPS is also a cloud service many times. See http://glesys.com/ they have cloud VPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, allow me to do a small **clarification** on your points like previous commenters did.

VPS **can** be cloud-based, meaning that the provider uses a variety of technologies such as virtualization, load-balancing etc. to offer you a server instance with all the flexibility/scalability of the resources (CPU,RAM,IO,Network) at your service. Cloud computing semantics are pretty broad, so I won't extend this anymore.

Your options for hosting a Java application (this belongs to SaaS service model) are the following:

1. Use a **PaaS** service model (Platform as a Service).
2. Use a **IaaS** service model (Infrastructure as a Service).

Number 1 means that you will use a ready-to-use **platform**  to build and run your Java applications. The platform will also provide you with some API and extensibility points (this varies a lot) for your application, and it will help you by placing a somehow flexible but **easy-to-configure** layer of abstraction between your application and the underlying infrastructure (OS,network etc). This is **usually cheaper**, easier to set-up and maintain, BUT you are depended on the platform itself and the limitations it has. This looks like more to what **Google App Engine** does.

Number 2 usually means that you will use an instance of a **preconfigured OS image** that the provider offers. The flavors vary in terms of the actual operation system (a Linux distro, windows). This allows you to have **even more** flexibility and customization to your needs. You can virtually configure everything on the OS level, including the lower layers of the stack. However, this means that you have to do most of the configuration on the OS level. This is a quite more expensive solution, but allows to have **all the control you need**. In addition, scalability won't be an issue - a good provider is able migrating your OS instance to anywhere inside his infrastructure, offering adequate resource provisioning for your needs. This looks like more to what **Amazon Elastic Cloud** does.

While all of the above may sound too generic, it's really up to your application needs. If you don't need to manage in detail resources belonging to the low layers, you can go to the comfort of a PaaS provider, **helping you to reduce development and maintenance costs**. If you need to have all the power you can, go for an IaaS solution, but bear in mind the higher costs involved.

A good cloud solution along with a scalable design of your application will allow you to expand quickly with minimal costs. Interesting **examples** are a lot of famous Facebook applications, that grew up rapidly. Cloud-based services usually succeed into lowering overall costs because they can dynamically allocate resources, allowing you to use **computing as an utlity** (pay-as-you-go).

Comment: May be this will shed more light on "flexibility" of Cloud. http://www.biztechafrica.com/article/flexibility-cloud-what-does-it-really-mean/7570/

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the different between CLOUD Hosting and traditional VPS.

Cloud Hosting is nothing but a traditional VPS hosting with advanced infrastructure. Cloud hosting is composed of array of disks and array of computing servers. If any of your computing station or disk storage is failed, everything is switched the next available computing station and disk storage. Beauty of the cloud is, your 1 computing station can be in NY data center and another can be in LA data center.

In the traditional VPS hosting, your computing and data storage - everything is on a single physical node. If that node goes down, everything is down.

Another benefit in Cloud VPS is instant scalability. Your Cloud server can grow or shrink on-the-fly based on your requirements.

APART from this, there is no major different between cloud vps and a traditional vps hosting.

Pricing is almost similar (cloud is 10% to 20% costly compared to traditional VPS).

I am more conversant with Windows VPS, so, I do not have any idea bout JVM or linux VPS.